# get distinct base on 2 or more Values from array in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, find, unique, distinct

**I have an array as shown below.**

[image]

**I want this pattern:**

[image]

**I want to Get distinct "CityRef" and "City".**
then find all item in association with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=52&ssc=27&pln=22&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUygVzmA8gIwFYOLAXhgG0AoGGAb3IoEsATALhgEYAaGmWqBAWwDkAhrwTMA5D2gsxHCjGDcAngCUEAM2btOCqIqEjmAIgAy4euEOyYAXyvU5DZgCYrXHgOGiYEhNCcztJVUNVlcdPU8jUzBzMEsaWxp7OiYYAGZXbj59Lx9oNIC5cODnMKUcowAFQThaCHiKa1IAXVJSWjAeODVBYAQYAHE4EGQABwR6AEl3CAAhRQBhJSoaYvVmMGReTAQ4VfLImGhasABzKyzeCGYAQTg4QUUAHmSUja2duFc3bMPjjtOCQAfKQmqRQJBYKdhmMJlhcPgYERECg0PC8FAAHSIejIPpPIYjcZTGbzJa6YjNIEACmp0KJEzuD0UbB%20vAAlEigSs5DAADZIeDqDoTaZ8JE83kOVKXTEMb68y4VNly9w5Tg2Nq8iHQGC8QRQYAACwm5MUEvpsPoTMemLUHXo1PCXPkSkxazUSIIRFlHvZAG4NbRPdT9YaTfQzZzXlKw8bTW7LhBMaNkBAjdTEPawKL3OyNbyUagwDBLcSbYoNWDeWXGfdban09SY9qgusVR6FUUDgYOz2EF26DNmMQsyKSXxWrzrPmNUW0KWYeX65XbCRmrOdSABZi%20SBTnSl3CcBj2UA).

```
interface GroupedItemsByCity {
  cityRef: number
  cityName: string,
  items: Array<{
    id: number,
    itemName: string
  }>
}

const groupedObject = returnObject.reduce<GroupedItemsByCity[]>((groupedArray, item) => {
    // New slimmer item to push later
    let refinedItem = {
        id: item.id,
        itemName: item.itemName
    }

    const matchedCity = groupedArray.find(city => city.cityRef === item.cityRef); // Check if the new structure already has a matching parent city for current item.
    if (matchedCity) {
        // If it does, push the item onto the existing city object.
        matchedCity.items.push(refinedItem)
        return groupedArray
    }

    // If it doesn't set up a new city and add the item to it
    groupedArray.push({
        cityRef: item.cityRef,
        cityName: item.cityName,
        items: [refinedItem]
    })

    return groupedArray
}, [])

console.log(groupedObject)
```